# read-syntax function for postfix interpreter in racket

Tags: racket, interpreter, postfix-notation

I write a read-syntax function but ı get this error. my **read-syntax** function is this:

```
(define (read-syntax path port)
  (for([line (port->lines port)])
    (parse-line line)))
```

The error is this:

```
Module Language: only a module expression is allowed, either
#lang <language-name>
or
(module <name> <language> ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each racket file is a module.

The file must start with defining the module.

The easy starting way is to have

```
#lang racket
```

as the first line of your module.

Description of this is in the Racket Guide https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html